# Problem showing the 'size' attribute for a 'file_field' using Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I have a form like this:

```
<%= form_for(@user, ... ) do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.file_field :avatar, :id => "test_id", :style => "display: block", :size => "13" %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

When I go to see the source of the page, this is the HTML code generated:

```
<input type="file" style="display: block;" name="user[avatar]" id="test_id">
```

that means the 'size' attribute there isn't.

I tried on Firefox, Chrome and Safari: same output, but it seems to have everything set correctly.

Is it a problem related to RoR3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually found that the size attribute is intentionally left out of the Rails source code here:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/75366cb82dc6fa4b3dada2a450dda18496f3eddd/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L734

"to_input_field_tag("file", options.update({:size => nil})"

Don't know why but glad to hear you found a workaround.

Comment: super annoying. I don't care if the `size` attribute isn't valid html5. FF on Linux ignores the css width of my file field, but listens to the `size` attribute, so I would like to use it. It's not perfect, but this question helped me get it to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659734/adding-size-option-to-file-field-tag-in-rails

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround by specifying the size in the style.

```
<%= f.file_field :avatar, :style=>"width: 13px" %>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, so simple.

Answer (score 1):

Ya seems so but..

I thought of another alternative :
jquery ..

```
$('#test_id').attr('size', 1);
```

bingo!!

Answer (score 0):

The `size` of a file field isn't configurable due to how browsers choose to render them and has nothing to do with Rails.