# adding size option to file_field tag in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, form-helpers

**ANSWERED**

I actually found the answer while formulating the question but I'm posting it any way since some might find this useful(as said here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49922/should-i-continue-adding-a-question-if-i-have-found-the-answer-myself)

I'm having trouble adding size to a file field in ROR3. Here was my syntax:

```
= f.file_field :file, :size => "11"
```

this doesnt appear but creates an file input field with this:

```
<input type="file" name="soap_test_zip_file[file]" id="soap_test_zip_file_file">
```

now I KNOW I made it work before so I looked into some old code and found this:

```
= file_field_tag :file, :size => 11
```

which outputs this:

```
<input type="file" size="11" name="file" id="file">
```

which gives me the correct size, but the wrong file id and name. So I tried this:

```
<input type="file" size="11" name="soap_test_file_file" id="soap_test_file_file">
```

which gives me the RIGHT ID, but the WRONG NAME. Question is how do I reproduce that file_field but with the size?

I looked into this answer by Ryan Bigg btw: [Problem showing the 'size' attribute for a 'file_field' using Ruby on Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756636/problem-showing-the-size-attribute-for-a-file-field-using-ruby-on-rails-3/4756758#4756758)

and he's saying it's a cross browser thing that they render file fields differently. That is the case, but I would like to render a short file field IF the browser can handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used:

```
= file_field_tag :soap_test_zip_file, {:name => 'soap_test_zip_file[file]', :size => 11}
```

This made me override the name(for the controller) and the size

Answer (score 0):

doesn't seem to work for me..

I thought of another alternative :
jquery ..

```
$('#user_photo_photo').attr('size', 1);
```

bingo!!

Comment: size only works in FF as far as i tested(didnt check IE and opera). webkit won't follow this size but instead will follow the input width defined in your css

Comment: I agree size works only on FF.. sorry for the mistake .
But your solution doesn't work for me. I am still unable to set the width of the text box for file input. any solution ?

Comment: which browser are you using and how are you setting its size? the size attribute or the width in css?

Comment: I want it to support all browser .. :)
If I try reducing the width it doesn't properly work in FF
If I set size it doesn't work in IE.
What I have done is I have file input and on above that (using z index) I have placed an image. So when the image is clicked the browse button in file filed is simulated . so if I set size now it doesn't work in IE and if I set width it doesn't work in FF . Thank you

Comment: you set a size for it to work in ff and set the width for IE. you will have to use different styles for both as they render it very differently

Answer (score 0):

If you want to not rewrite the name attribute you can do something like this :

**keep your form**

```
= f.file_field :file, :size => "11"
```

**add an override for the file_field method**

```
# lib/my_override.rb

module ActionView
  module Helpers
    module FormHelper   
      def file_field(object_name, method, options = {})
        InstanceTag.new(object_name, method, self, options.delete(:object)).to_input_field_tag("file", options.update({:size => options[:size]}))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**And load it through an initializer**

```
# config/initializers/load_lib.rb    

require 'my_override'
```